# C# Get next control's location inside a panel

Tags: c#

I have buttons under each others and want to change the next button's location if I click on a button and if there is another button, how can I achieve this?

I can't use `panel1.Controls["name"]` or `panel1.Controls.Find("name", true);` because they are randomly generated buttons and I don't know their names.

Comment: How precisely do you define "_next_"? What makes one button the next of another? And what do you precisely mean when saying "_and if there is another button_"? Since you talk about having button**s** (plural), there is always a button and another button, so what's that "_if_" business you are talking all about? Please edit and clarify your question. Try to be precise and concise.

Comment: When you randomly generate a button, save it to a class level array of buttons so you can access it later.

Comment: winforms, web ? please clarify

Comment: Yes, winforms @jmvcollaborator

Comment: what do you mean by next control ?

Comment: There are buttons below each other, so if I click on a button then I want to hide the clicked button with the visible property and set the below button's position to the clicked button's position. I can access to the clicked button but how can I access to the next (below) button?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the question is complete enough for an answer, but it sounds like when you randomly generate a button, you need save it to a class level array of buttons so you can access it later.

Below is a small example that creates random buttons and adds them to a class-level array. These buttons can then be accessed from any method in the class. It's up to you how you want to implement your functionality, but in my sample below I added a dynamic click event that moves the "next" button in the array:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Button> randomButtons = new List<Button>();

    private void GenerateRandomButtons()
    {
        var btnStartTop = 10;
        var btnLeft = 10;
        var btnHeight = 20;
        var btnWidth = 500;
        var btnPadding = 5;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var rndButton = new Button();
            rndButton.Left = btnLeft;
            rndButton.Height = btnHeight;
            rndButton.Width = btnWidth;
            rndButton.Top = btnStartTop + (i * btnHeight) + (i * btnPadding);
            rndButton.Text = "Random Button #" + (i + 1);
            rndButton.Visible = true;

            // Click event will change the next button's location
            rndButton.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                var nextButtonIndex = i == 9 ? 0 : i + 1;
                randomButtons[nextButtonIndex].Left += 20;
            };

            this.Controls.Add(rndButton);
            randomButtons.Add(rndButton);
        }
   }
```